# Passing non-ASCII characters between two asp.net MVC web applications will not be recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two asp.net mvc-4 and mvc-5 web applications,, now inside my first asp.net mvc i have the following `WebClient` to call an action method (Home/CreateResource) on the second web application :-

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
         {
          var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cr);             
          string url = scanningurl + "Home/CreateResource";
          Uri uri = new Uri(url);
          wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
          wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
          output = wc.UploadString(uri, data);
         }
```

now inside the `data` object which is being transferred to the second action method, it contain a value for password and this value in my case is `££123` which have 2 non-ASCII characters ..

now on the second action method it will accept the above value as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce if there is a way to pass non-ASCII characters between the 2 action methods ? i check that on the first action method the password is being Serialized well , and also the password is being passed correctly from the view to the action method. but the problem is somewhere inside how the data is being transferred inside the network or how the model binder on the second action method is accepting the incoming data object??

Comment: How about `wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` before uploading the string?

Comment: @LocEngineer can you please adivce more on this  ? what will this do exactly ?

Comment: The UploadString and UploadStringAsync methods use this property to convert the specified string to a Byte array before uploading the string. Using `GetBytes()` on the receiving end should get you the proper string. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LocEngineer yes adding wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; will allow to transfer non-ASCII characters correctly ... but i did not explicitly used GetBytes() on the receiving end (the second actino method),, seems this will be done automatically ?? is this correct ?

Comment: My bad. Yes it seems that this will be done automatically.

Comment: @LocEngineer but why the Encoding is required only for non-ASCII characters ??  i mean passing charecters such as $ , % , ^ , & will be recognized correctly by the receiving actino emthod without encoding .. second question is the Encoding.UTF8 will give the same result as URL encoding ? i mean the final object after encoding it with UTF8 will be the same if i do HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data)?

Comment: $, %, &, and ^ are all in the first 128 characters, i.e. US ASCII. The Pound sign is not. And UTF8 is of course not the same as UrlEncoding. You will of course get proper results if you properly encode/decode the data. In your example you haven't, therefore the corruption. If you use a `WebClient`, then the proper way is to set the client's Encoding.

Comment: @LocEngineer can you adivce what do you exactly mean by "If you use a WebClient, then the proper way is to set the client's Encoding. " ???

Comment: You have `using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) ` - so you are literally `using` a `WebClient`. Ergo, using the WebClient's built-in `Encoding` property is the proper way to upload non-ASCII characters. So if you put `wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` after `wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);` and before `output = wc.UploadString(uri, data);` you should be fine.

Comment: @LocEngineer i think i am missing something here ,, do you mean the order of the wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; and wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token); matters? so i need to encode after the Authorization  ???

Comment: You need to set encoding before Uploadstring. That is all that matters. Why don't you simply try it out?

Comment: @LocEngineer yes i already try this and it solved my problem .. but i am not sure how the receiving action method was able to understand the encoded data , without additional effort ? i mean when i call an action method using UploadString will the receiving action method automatically decode the received string using UTF8 decoding  ????

Comment: @LocEngineer now generally speaking is there any Risk/Issue if i always use wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 instead of the defualt encoding inside my WebClient()'s methods mainly  UploadString() & DownloadString() methods ?? and if there is not any issue why by defualt the WebClient does not use UTF8 encoding by defualt ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To summarize:

You need to specify the WebClient's Encoding property if you want to transmit non-ASCII (or high-ASCII) characters such as £.

The order in which to set the property values is not important in this case, provided it is set before calling `UploadString`.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cr);
    string url = scanningurl + "Home/CreateResource";
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
    wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    output = wc.UploadString(uri, data);
}
```

In case you wish to *download* data from a website using WebClient, make sure to set the encoding to the value used by that website.

Comment: thanks for the reply..  first question do i need to specify the content type as follow "application/json; charset=utf-8" instead of just "application/json" since i am uploading the data using UTF8 encoding ? second question now when i uploadstring there are two operations will be executed; first one is to upload the string to the specified url , second operation is to receive the API reply and assign it to the output variable is this correct ? so does the encoding affects both how the string is being uploaded and also how the API response will be assigned to the output variable ?

Comment: or the encoding does not affect how the API response is being assigned to the output variable.. becuase in my case i am facing this behavioure ..Now if i REMOVE the wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; and the API rely back "The resource named ££123 has been added successfully" ,, then the output variable will have a value such as "The resource named ÂÂ123 has been added successfully", where the non-ASCII characters inside the reply (which are ££ in my case) will be assigned wrongly as ÂÂ .

Comment: so this mean the wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; will mainly affect how the data will be uploaded and also how the output will be handled , because if I ADD wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;  and the API reply back "The resource named ££123 has been added successfully"  , then the output variable will get the correct value with the non-ASCII characters  ££ in it...

Answer (score 2):

simply change `wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");` to `wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json;charset=utf-8");`

Comment: you are assuming that the API will look for the content type ? what ifthe external API does not look for the content type ,, as in my case?

Comment: if you know that external api dones not look for content type by default it is ASCII if you found non-acsii character convert it to ascii one and make sure it was not for typing

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while back. The solution was to use `UploadDataAsync`

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json");
    client.UploadDataAsync(new Uri(apiUrl), "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although UTF-8 theoretically should be capable of encoding any characters you need (as it has a muti-byte encoding scheme to handle extended chracters), an alternative solution:

**Base 64 encode your text.**

To encode `s`:

```
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));
```

To decode `encoded`:

```
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encoded));
```